# How can I set mounted(computed, watch..) property outside vue instance

Tags: vue.js

I want to set computed, mounted, watch property to outside the vue instance.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  // options
})
vm._data.test = 'test' //data ok.
vm.methods =function(){
    console.log("method ok");
};
vm.computed= ?
vm.watch =?
vm.mounted=?
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Could be XY problem.

Comment: That's not possible. You can update only `data`. Please read vue documentation carefully

Comment: You can use [Mixinis](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

Comment: There are already instance methods for `watch` and `mounted.`  https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch and https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount